# How to subtract values from a same column in DAX on the basis of other selected values from a different column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I habe data like this.

Date.      Type  Value

19/1/2020.  A.    12

19/1/2020.  B.    20
..

20/1/2020.  A.    40
..

20/1/2020.  B.    20
.
.
.

I want to calculate A - B and plot it on a graph. I can't write Type = A in a formula to filter as I have many types. But i just want to subtract only two types at once, not more.

any help will highly be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to pivot your table like below:

Note that I have named the table as "Types" and your new column as "Difference"

[image]

Then you can create a calculated column like below:

[image]